# Meteor js - unable to insert data on Mongo through console

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm following an udemy course on Meteor.

**Steps to replicate my problem:**

1) On CMD:

```
meteor create Leaderboard
cd Leaderboard
meteor npm install
meteor run
(server starts, localhost:3000)
```

2) Then, I deleted the contents of main.css, main.html & main.js (under client folder).

3) Opened main.js and added the following line:

```
PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');
```

On Chrome's console I typed 'PlayersList' and got the following:

```
M…o.Collection {_transform: null, _connection: Connection, _collection: LocalCollection, _name: "players", _driver: LocalCollectionDriver…}
```

---

**THE PROBLEM**

When I type this on console:

```
PlayersList.insert({ name: 'David', score: 0 });
```

This is the Error:

```
"eebRFhA9vbSfHzPKk"
meteor.js?hash=e3f53db…:930 insert failed: Method '/players/insert' not found
```

Why am I getting it? I followed the exact steps provided by the instructor. What's wrong here?

Comment: What's abt pub/sub ? Do you have insecure on ?

Comment: I've done the exact steps described above, I'm kind of new to this and from what I've read insecure is on by default unless removed. I'm going to try that. EDIT: Just stopped the server and removed insecure, same thing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is caused by the collection not having been defined on the server, only on the client.

The default app created by `meteor create app` contains two `main.js` files, one in the `client` and one in `server` folder. These specially-named folders work exactly as you'd expect - the content in them is only loaded on the client or server. Apparently you added the collection definition only to the one in `client`. To fix this, if you put a file outside these specially-named folders - say create a folder named `collections`, and add a `PlayersList.js` file there and define your collection there, then it will be loaded by both and work.

Alternatively (this is the recommended method when developing a larger app) if you put the file that defines the collection into a folder named `imports` then you can `import` that to your server and client code separately, instead of Meteor auto-including it. You can read more about Meteor application structure [here](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html).

Comment: I wasn't aware you had to do that. Anyway, per your instructions I created a folder called 'imports' in the root directory, added a new file 'leaderboard.js' and added my collection there. After that I imported 'imports/leaderboard.js' into both the client & the server. Now I get the following error: **insert failed: Access denied**

Comment: Started from scratch using the --bare option upon creation. Works fine now.

Comment: @Rosenberg You had removed the `insecure` package apparently. Once you do that, you need to define additional rules to allow insertion. But you'll get to that later. Good luck with studying Meteor :)

Comment: I found an easier way to solve it, just to put  PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');   in the main.js at the server folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-
PlayersList._collection.insert({ name: 'David', score: 0 });

Comment: Can you explain ?